# Is it possible to embed git within my website to manage image history?

Tags: .net, git, .net-core

I'm working on a .net core website for our company's design team. The website will showcase the design images we have in our collection.

One of the requirements is to allow our designers to have a history, review process, etc for design files. Instantly, I thought that instead of reinventing the wheel, perhaps the site can utilize Git for it's "database". I'm not sure if this is possible, or what framework out there allows for this. Additionally, I don't want our designers to be able to throw in just any file, only files with specific extensions (photoshop, jpg, png, etc.) make sense -- throwing in a random .txt file doesn't. The main reason I am leaning towards Git is that it also has branching, so a designer can branch and work on updating a lot of designs and then merge back in when they are done.

I tried to google for this for hours, but I don't know if I'm looking at "Embedded Git" or "System Git" or hosting my own Git Server, if I can take the code and modify the server code or if it has the features I need already, etc. Basically, I can do my own research and try to get something going if I just knew where to start with in terms of frameworks, etc.

---

I noticed that Microsoft did something similar on VSTS with their new Wiki feature. It's an embedded repository for markdown files. It allows you to clone the entire wiki and they have security built around the wiki. I want to do the exact same thing, but for images instead of markdown.

[image]

Comment: git is already "embedded" or "system"...

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I'm not familiar with the terminology, I only mentioned the two "embedded" and "system" because those two terms came up in google searches, and I don't quite understand them.

Answer (score 0):

**Git** is not designed to work with binary files like images. If you still want to use it, you can write a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to prevent unwanted files (.txt) from being commited. 
On your website, you can install a simple [gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) but you cannot benefit from git's diff features with images... Maybe with a plugin?

Not mentionning that designers will have to learn how to use this dangerous tool...

I don't mean to discourage you, but I think Git may not be the best tool for your needs.

Comment: Why do you consider git to be a “dangerous tool”?

Comment: You can lose work easily if you don't know what you are doing : delete branch, overwritting by merge, rebase... Of course, as always if you know the tool you can be confident enough to call it safe. But what about designers? They don't know a thing about VCS!

Comment: All of the things you described can be easily recovered using git tools. Designers just need a decent gui.

Comment: git sucks with binary files, period. Thats why many game developers do not use git. Perforce, and subversion are both alright with binary files.